# Why doesn't my return work?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am stuck on this code and can't get through it no matter how much I work on it. I need set the values in the file to the array in a method and then return it. Then those values need to be set for temp. I keep being told that I need to return a double[] but I am and when I try adding that brackets on it tells me cant convert from double to double[]. I could also use advice on anything else that may be wrong. Please help, I'm on the verge of smacking my face into a wall.....
     Also I cut out the location of the file as the location had my name in it so I know that's not a proper location.

```
 //Java Eclipse
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.*;
 public class TempDriver {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    double [] temp = new double[12];
    Scanner file;
}

    public static double[] readFile(double temp [], Scanner file){
    int i = 0;
    try { 
        file = new Scanner(new File(""));

        while(file.hasNextDouble()) {
            temp[i] = file.nextDouble();
            i++;
        }

    file.close();

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println ("File not found");
    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println ("Array index too large");

    } 
    return temp[i];
}
```

}

Comment: First off, why are you creating an array with zero elements in it? Second, `readFile()` is expecting an argument of type `Scanner`, and you're passing an array to it.

Comment: What if an exception occurs, what are you returning then?

Comment: This code has multiple issues that would need addressing. I'd recommend breaking down the code that you have and learn to do one thing at a time.

Comment: If you keep making edits I can't write my answer. Please decide what code are you going to show us.

Comment: I only made one edit...regardless my apologies for any problems and this is my final code.

Comment: OK, I will write again now :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are several things broken here, but nothing that can't be... oh wait, what *is* that?... Uh, nevermind.

Hey look, the question has been edited. Again.

Alright, your code is a mess, but at least it is much less messy than the original version. With some touches here and there, it should work, so don't worry. You're almost there!

1. Do a call to `readFile()` in `main()`.
2. You are not using the `Scanner file` received in `readFile()`, but creating your own inside the method *on top of the argument*. Use what you receive or take it out from the arguments list.
3. Return `temp` instead of `temp[i]`. The first is an array of double, while the latter is a double.

Here's your code with the mentioned fixes:

```java
//Java jEdit
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class TempDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //The array were you are going to put the data
        double[] temp = new double[12];
        //The Scanner you are going to read the numbers from
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("myfile.dat"));
        //Calling readFile()
        temp = TempDriver.readFile(temp, file);
        //Close the Scanner now that you are done using it
        file.close();
        //TODO: Display your fetched data here
    }

    public static double[] readFile(double[] temp, Scanner file){
        int i = 0;
        try {
            //Read numbers
            while (file.hasNextDouble()) {
                temp[i] = file.nextDouble();
                i++;
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println ("File not found");
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            System.out.println ("Array index too large");
        }
        //Return the array
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I kinda feel dumb now, I overthink my codes way too much haha. Your a lifesaver :).

Comment: Don't worry, we all mess things up in our first try. When in doubt about something, you can look up how other people do it to get some ideas. Good luck!